# Matlab "tdfread" very slow

Tags: matlab

I am working with tab delimited files currently (mixture of strings, doubles and integers) and use 'tdfread' command to import them into Matlab.  Works perfectly for small files but takes ages to import a reasonably large one.  Importing is actually the most time consuming part of the whole analysis.

Is there a quicker way of doing that?

File has a bit more that 4 million lines and took 1/2 hour to load.

Comment: `textscan` might be faster, but that's still a moderately large file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This is far from the largest chunk of data I need to analyse.  Maybe there's a way to import file in several blocks?

Comment: @nik you can specify a chunk size `N` with `textscan` using `C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N)`. I don't have the stats toolbox so I don't know if `tdfread` is a wrapper for a built-in or not. There's a pretty good chance it is, and probably for `dlmread` (which is a wrapper for `textscan`).

Comment: @nik also, I'm not sure if `tdfread` is smart about determining what type of data it's reading (i.e. integer vs. float). `textscan` allows you to specify the format of the data you're reading in, so you may be able to eliminate a significant amount of overhead by storing values as their correct data type. 4 million rows of integers takes up a lot less memory than 4 million rows of that same integer stored as a double.

Comment: Thanks @excaza.  You're right tdfread has indeed stored all of integers as doubles.  I will look into using textscan as long as it will allow me to specify datatype for each column separately.